# Radio group not working in android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I ahve made a simple radioButton demo in android.In that i have put a radiogroup with two radio buttons named "male" and "female"...and a button .I want is when one of them pressed the name related to that particular radiobutton should be in toast.I have tried as below thats not working:

**Activity.java**

```
package com.example.radiobuttondemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RadioButton rd1,rd2;
Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rd1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rd2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(rd1.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "male", 0).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Female", 0).show();
            }


        }
    });
    }



}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? When you debug does it enter the onClick()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `Button` b.

So when you're doing `b.setOnClickListener`, your program throws a `NullPointerException` and make your app closed.

Comment: ohk...k...bro...m begginer ..so made silly mistakes...thanks for helping me...bro..!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've always used RadioGroup for my radio buttons. If you didn't use that, how would it know to uncheck one radio button when you checked the other radio button?

See http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Now if you're dealing with a normal checkbox, your approach would be fine I suppose. A normal checkbox wouldn't need to know about its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You must bind your button with the Button object (that you named b) in your MainActivity class.
There is an action listener on b, but b is not binded...

Comment: Just add : `b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);`

Answer (score 0):

Do the check against RadioButton group itself:

```
switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case rd1:
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "male", 0).show();
                     break;
            case rd2:
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Female", 0).show();
                     break;
)
```